# how to simulate button press during installation through bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, system-administration

i am trying to automate a package installation on ubuntu using a bash script..
i am connected through SSH
but during the installation, the setup shows a dialogbox asking for password and other details..
there are two buttons ok and cancel..
the script stops when that dialogbox pops up, waiting for human input..

my question is, how can we simulate the button press through bash script?
is there any command combo or any tricks?..
or if thats not possible, how to send the ENTER key to std input through script?

Comment: `printf "\n" | script` maybe?

Comment: What is the install command?